# Quartz.net - list of configuration properties

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I am new in quartz.NET. I was trying to find in documentation 3.x the list of available properties for config file but with no success. 
Is there any complete list or sample config files from examples are all we have?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961235/where-is-the-documentation-for-quartz-net-configuration-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the documentation for Quartz.NET configuration files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961235/where-is-the-documentation-for-quartz-net-configuration-files)

Answer (score -5):

This is the official documentation from them

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html

Comment: Thanks, I know it but there is any information about the available property list. At least I could not find it.